# Crystal Reports crashes first run. Works fine after that

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Everything works fine on the development machine(win8 x64)

When deployed to a windows xp machine 32bit the program works fine, until I try to print out a report. It gets this unhandled exception:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.
```

http://pastebin.com/b0SbcZJM (full details of exception)

After quitting the application and opening it again. The reports work as they should.

Any help? I have been smashing my head against the wall for a few days now.

Comment: Hi which version of CR are you using?

Comment: I am using Crystal Reports 13

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue @AttackingHobo? We're facing the exact same thing. Our reports work fine, then out of the blue it'll fall over with the same exception.

Comment: @LokiSinclair Nope, never fixed it. This and a few other unsolvable illogical bugs caused me to switch to DevExpress. It's a bit pricy, but it works, and they have great documentation and amazing support. The reporting feature in DevExpress is a bit harder to get used to than Crytal Reports, but its much more flexible.